# Trino UDF Plugin: Which is the corresponding Java type to map(string,string)

Tags: java, scala, trino

I am creating a plugin to host an UDF, it is an http_get function, receiving the `httpAddress` path, the query `parameters` and the request `headers`. It is implemeted in scala:

```
  @ScalarFunction(value = "http_get", deterministic = true)
  @Description("Returns the result of an Http Get request")
  @SqlType(value = StandardTypes.VARCHAR)
  def httpGetFromArrayMap(
                           @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) httpAddress: Slice,
                           @SqlType(constants.STRING_MAP) parameters: ImmutableMap[Slice, Slice],
                           @SqlNullable @SqlType(constants.STRING_MAP) headers: ImmutableMap[Slice, Slice],
                         ): String = {

    val stringHeaders = castSliceMap(headers)
    val stringParams = castSliceMap(parameters)
    val request = Http(httpAddress.toStringUtf8).headers(stringHeaders).params(stringParams)
    val stringResponse = request.asString.body
    stringResponse
  }
```

When running on trino, it raises the following exception:

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Exact implementation of http_get do not match expected java types.
```

The problem is: What is the corresponding java type to `map(varchar,varchar)`?

I've tried Many:

- Scala Map[String, String]
- Java Map<String, String>
- Java Map<Slice, Slice>
- ImmutableMap<String, String>
- ImmutableMap<Slice, Slice>

Can't find any example of plugin implementing a function which receives a map.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar at all with Trino UDF*

According to the examples you can find in Trino repository, the type to use for a `SqlType("map(X,y)")` is `io.trino.spi.block.Block`.

The `Block` can then be manipulated to extract its content as if it were a regular `Map`.

See for instance: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/core/trino-main/src/main/java/io/trino/operator/scalar/MathFunctions.java#L1340